# How to enter form data into a mysql database using an array?

Tags: php

I have a form that submits steps and ingredients for recipes that I am practicing with for another project. I have set the form up to submit the data in an array, but I can't get the PHP code correct to insert the data into the database. I have pasted the form layout here. The form comes up as part of another PHP page that is called when the user enters a recipe name to add to the database. I would like to have 10 separate step entries on this form if I can figure out how to insert them correctly into the database.

```
<form action="add_recipe2.php" method="post">
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Add a Recipe</legend>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>Recipe Name:</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="recipename" value="$recipename"></td>
           </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Step:</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="recipe[0][step]" placeholder="1"></td>
                <td>Ingredients:</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="recipe[0][ingredients]" placeholder="Ingredients"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Step:</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="recipe[1][step]" placeholder="2"></td>
                <td>Ingredients:</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="recipe[1][ingredients]" placeholder="Ingredients"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Step:</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="recipe[2][step]" placeholder="3"></td>
                <td>Ingredients:</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="recipe[2][ingredients]" placeholder="Ingredients"></td>
            </tr>

        </table>
        <button type="submit">Add a Recipe</button>
        <button type="reset">Reset</button>

    </fieldset>
</form>
```

This is the PHP that enters the data into the database. The problem is when I only add two records to the database the last record still inserts, but it inserts a blank line. I need a way to only add the data that is being passed from the form even if it is only one line. I have researched this a long time and this represents one of the answers that I found. However, it still does not stop inserting into the database when there is no more data from the form.

```
$recipename = $_REQUEST["recipename"];

$conn = mysql_connect("localhost","user","password") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("test");

foreach($_POST['recipe'] as $recipe) { 

// Add to database
$sql1 = "INSERT INTO `recipes` (recipe, step, ingredients) VALUES   ('".$_POST['recipename']."', '".$recipe['step']."', '".$recipe['ingredients']."')";
mysql_query($sql1, $conn) or die(mysql_error());
 } //end foreach
```

I just can't figure this out. I need help. I suspect that I have to have a way to tell how many records I am actually sending if it is not the number of form entries that exist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You  will need to test if values in the array component are filled in before querying them.  Also, you MUST escape all the insert values against SQL injection with `mysql_real_escape_string()`:

```
$recipename = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['recipename']);

foreach($_POST['recipe'] as $recipe) { 
  // Only insert if step is non-empty.
  if (!empty($recipe['step']) {
    // Add to database

    // Escape against SQL injection
    $recipe['step'] = mysql_real_escape_string($recipe['step'];
    $recipe['ingredients'] = mysql_real_escape_string($recipe['ingredients'];

    $sql1 = "INSERT INTO `recipes` (recipe, step, ingredients) VALUES   ('".$recipename."', '".$recipe['step']."', '".$recipe['ingredients']."')";
    mysql_query($sql1, $conn) or die(mysql_error());
  }
}
```

Comment: This should work, but it does not insert anything except the recipe name. I tried a var_dump to see what the recipe step is and that showed up as 0. The form is sending only the last entry for the step and ingredients. I don't know how to get past this.

Comment: I tried this again by reloading everything and it seems to work now. I don't know where the issue was when I first tried it. Thank you sincerely for helping me with this problem.

Comment: @user1137742 Glad it's sorted out - happy to help

Answer (score 0):

The fact is, even if the user doesn't fill in the information in the form for recipe[3], the empty values are still being submitted.

You have to validate your data before insert into the database:

```
function isValidRecipe($recipe){
    // returns true if ingredients and step are not empty
    return !(empty($recipe['ingredients']) || empty($recipe['step']));
}
foreach($_POST['recipe'] as $recipe) {
if (isValidRecipe($recipe)){
    // Add to database
    $sql1 = "INSERT INTO `recipes` (recipe, step, ingredients) VALUES ('".$_POST['recipename']."', '".$recipe['step']."', '".$recipe['ingredients']."')";
        mysql_query($sql1, $conn) or die(mysql_error());
    }
}
```

Note that this is the minimum validation, you should probably check everything more thoroughly.

Comment: I tried this out and it seems to work. I am still testing, but it looks good so far. Thank you for taking the time to help me out.